# Installing a apk file ,in android emulator

Tags: android

I have an apk file ,how do i install it  in android emulator. I am working under Linux operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command from a shell.

```
adb install yourapkname.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing .apk file in emulator ...

go to command prompt

type....  adb install yourApp.apk

but in your system ,if more than one emulator or/and device are running then you have to select particular emulator/device  and than  install .apk file

Answer (score 0):

Goto Shell/Terminal/, reach at android-sdk/tools directory then

```
adb install fileName.apk // (u can run this command on windows)
or 
./adb install fileName.apk  //( u can run this command on linux)
```

use full for me ([Installing .apk file on Emulator in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208764/installing-apk-file-on-emulator-in-linux))

Answer (score 0):

if you have eclipse then right click your project and click Run as->Android Application. It will ask your avd device and click that. After few sec your app will be loaded in your emulator. Best of luck:)