# Installing .apk file on Emulator in Linux

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate the Zxing Bar code scanner into an application, but I need to install the bar code application on the emulator first. I already downloaded the .apk file. How do I install it on the emulator? I'm running Ububtu.

Answer (score 4):

**Goto Shell/Terminal/, reach at android-sdk/tools directory then**

```
adb install fileName.apk 
or ./adb install fileName.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start emulator.
2. `android-sdk-linux/platform-tools > ./adb -e install Test-debug.apk`